# Small Configurations in Random Hypergraphs

Tags: random-graphs, hypergraph

I have a somewhat technical question regarding the distribution of small hypergraphs in randomly chosen hypergraphs.  (My hope is that this is something that can be done using standard ideas about random hypergraphs, and that I'm just not comfortable enough with the area to see how.)

I begin with some large vertex set $G$, $|G|=n$, and choose a random $k$-uniform hypergraph $\Gamma$ by independently placing each edge from ${G\choose k}$ in $\Gamma$ with probability $p$.  (I expect the relevant case to be of the form $p\approx n^{-1/c}$ for some $c$.)  I fix some $d$.

Now I fix some small $k$-uniform hypergraph $H$ on $n'$ vertices with at most $d$ edges, and I'm interested in those tuples $\vec x\in G^{n'}$ such that $H$ is a sub-hypergraph (not necessarily induced) of the restriction of $\Gamma$ to $\vec x$.  (I think of $H$ as defining which edges I care about, and then I'm interested in those tuples in which all the edges mandated by $H$ are actually present in $\Gamma$.)  I'll write $\Gamma_H\subseteq G^{n'}$ for the set of such tuples.

Now suppose I have some set $A\subseteq G^{n'}$, and I want to estimate its probability as a fraction of $\Gamma_H$.  One way to do so would be to define
$$\mu_H(A)=\frac{|A\cap\Gamma_H|}{|\Gamma_H|}.$$

But another way to do so would be to partition $H$ into two sub-hypergraphs, $H_0,H_1$, and ask about
$$\mu'_H(A)=\frac{1}{|\Gamma_{H_0}|}\sum_{\vec x\in \Gamma_{H_0}}\frac{|\{\vec y\mid (\vec x,\vec y)\in A\cap\Gamma_H\}|}{|\{\vec y\mid (\vec x,\vec y)\in\Gamma_H\}|}.$$

Let's say $\Gamma$ is $\delta$-good if for every set $A$,
$$|\mu_H(A)-\mu'_H(A)|<\delta.$$
It seems like to show that this holds, one could show that for "most" choices of $\vec x\in\Gamma_{H_0}$, $|\{\vec y\mid(\vec x,\vec y)\in\Gamma_H\}|$ is close to the value it ought to have.

I would like to show that for an appropriate choice of $p$, and with fixed values $k,d,n',\delta$, the probability that $\Gamma$ is $\delta$-good approaches $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  (I'd be particularly happy to 1) know what good choices of $p$ would be, or 2) show that this follows from an established notion of pseudo-randomness.)

(I actually need a more complicated case in which one partitions $H$ into three pieces $H_0,H_1,H_2$, and looks at the measures $\mu_H$ and $\mu'_H$ relative to "almost every" fixed tuple $\vec z\in\Gamma_{H_2}$, but perhaps I'll be able to derive that easily from an answer, or perhaps I'll end up asking a follow-up question.)

Comment: I can't give a proof of this offhand, but I know exactly where I'd look: Alon and Spencer (using large deviations)

Comment: $H$ and $\Gamma$ have the same vertex set?

Comment: @vzn: No.  I corrected a typo: it should say that H is a graph on n' vertices.  I expect to find many copies of H in $(G,\Gamma)$.

Comment: You might want to look up Russ Lyons -- this reminds me somewhat of some questions he considered maybe 5 years ago. 

Comment: found this question because am looking for "large" impossible configurations in "structured" hypergraphs whereas you are looking for small configurations in random hypergraphs. maybe some of the theory might meet up in the middle eventually...? =)

Comment: so is the intention something like $n \gg n'$? can anything more be said about the relation between $n$ and $n'$?

Comment: @vzn: I need the situation where n' is fixed and n is arbitrarily large relative to that, so $n>>n'$ is really the only condition on $n'$.

Comment: some work in hypergraphs is based on creating an analogy with/generalization of some classic graph theorems. is there a (rough?) graph analogy for this problem? can you say anything more about inspiration/motivation?

Comment: @vzn: The graph analog is the following: suppose $A$ is a subgraph of the random graph $\Gamma$, and I want to know the density of $A$. One way to find this is to divide the number of edges in $A$ by the number of edges in $\Gamma$. Another way is to look at each vertex $x$, and calculate $N_A(x)/N_\Gamma(x)$, and then take the average value of this to be the density of $A$. If $\Gamma$ is complete, these obviously give the same value. If $\Gamma$ is random then these should give roughly the same value because $N_\Gamma(x)$ is close to constant. (By $N_\Gamma(x)$, I mean the neighborhood.)

Comment: ok that helps some but still not following; it seems if you want to know the density of $A$ then you would look at $A$, not $\Gamma$. or also that any random subgraph of $\Gamma$ will tend to have the same density as $\Gamma$. is there something special about how $A$ is selected?

Comment: the partitioning into subhypergraphs seems similar to the szemeredi regularity lemma http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma ... 

Comment: In answer to your question from Oct 23 (which I hadn't seen, and missed the notification for), the statement I made in my last comment doesn't need anything special about $A$.  Both methods I described for finding the density of $A$ involve $A$; one of them *additionally* involves $\Gamma$.  As for the regularity lemma, I'm afraid I don't see the similarity beyond the fact that both mention partitions.